# compile error - Same type name in two classes

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, compiler-errors, uwp

everyone.

I am using `Visual Studio` to develop `uwp` application. The compiler says that type `FileMode` exists in both `MySql.Data.RT` and `System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives`. The error message is below.

```
Error CS0433 Type 'FileMode' exists in both 'MySql.Data.RT, Version=6.7.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' and 'System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

However, I have used the complete name of the type as following.

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
```

I don't know why there is still an error, any advice is welcome.

**EDIT:**

I don't think this question is duplicate because I could not find any way to modify the answer to the provided candidate duplicate question to solve the issue I encountered.

**EDIT:**

I eventually solved this issue myself. I found out that the namespace `System.IO` exists in two `dll` files, `MySql.Data.RT` and `System.IO.FileStream.Primitives`. That's why even I specified the full name of the object (`System.IO.FileMode`), the compiler still doesn't know which dll file it should references the object to. 
My solution is to add an alias to `MySql.Data.RT` as `MySQL`, and modify the code as following.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

=>

```
extern alias MySQL;
using MySQL::MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

**Note:**

One can add an alias to a reference via right click on it in the solution explorer and then click the `property` option, then the UI will appear.

Comment: What are the namespaces of both classes?

Comment: Have you done a clean?

Comment: From a first glance it looks like you have 2 namespaces with the class FileMode. This may cause a confusion when accessing FileMode. It doesn't happen in the code you wrote because you use the class' full name: System.IO.FileMode. Try using the full name each time you're using FileMode

Comment: @OriNachum I've used the full name when I am using `FileMode` everywhere in my project.

Comment: @DavidChen, did you try manually deleting the OBJ and BIN folders? (Not the right-click clean from VS)

Comment: @JoshuaDrake I cleaned and rebuild it, but it didn't work out.

Comment: @OriNachum, No I haven't. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Go the the Project's folder (Right click on the project, and then click Open Folder in File Explorer). You should see obj and bin folders. You can delete them both - VS generates them when you build your code. Edit: After deleting your code, try to build again

Comment: I disagree with the Duplicate Flag because the other question was bout the interaction of dlls, and within the scope of a web app, while this question is about compilation within the confines of a single solution.

Comment: @OriNachum Thanks for your advice, but it didn't work out. Also, it occurred to me that it was the first time I wanted to build the project when the error appeared.

Comment: @DavidChen, Where did you get the MySQL.DATA.RT from? I couldn't locate it in MySQL.DATA namespace. I'm trying to reproduce the issue in my end.

Comment: @OriNachum I added the reference to my project. Below is the path.
`C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.7.9\Assemblies\RT\MySql.Data.RT.dll`

Comment: @DavidChen, What project did you start? When I try to recreate on Windows 7, Visual Studio 2015, .NET Frameowkr 4.5.2 I get the error: The Project targets `.NET Framework` while the file references `.NETCore`

Comment: @OriNachum universal windows application

Comment: It is acceptable to accept your own answers. Your edit should be an answer.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Because it is marked as duplicate now, it can't be answered now. I've flagged it for moderator intervention. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @EshanSajjad This doesn't seem a duplicate issue as marked - the other issue refers to a server with specific files reference errors, while this is about namespaces. OP wasn't able to adapt the solution to this issue.